# sum of a list in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm beginner in functional programming and scheme language.

I found a way to build the sum of a list:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      0
      (+ (car lst) (sum (cdr lst)))))

(sum (list 1 2 3))
```

My question is: is there a way to build the sum of a list without a extra function like sum, just using the "+" function like this:

```
(+ 1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can `apply` list of arguments to a function. So in this case you can:

```
> (apply + (list 1 2 3))
6
```

Answer (score 2):

The reference for MIT/Gnu-Scheme says, that `+` takes ANY number of arguments. 
I am sure, that this standard.

In general:

```
(define (foo . args) ....)
```

is used like `(foo)` or `(foo x)` or `(foo x y)`, `(foo x y z)`, .... . Inside `foo` the args will be `'()`, `(x)`, `(x y)` or `(x y z)`.

See exercise 2.20 in SICP or MIT/Scheme Reference 9.2 chap 2.1

This means:

For the arithmetic procedures `+`, `*`, `-` and `/` your procedure is not necessary, because they are defined for any number of arguments, including zero and one.
This is also true for some other built-in procedures. 
For your own procedures you can use the *dotted-tail* notation.

You can download the MIT/Scheme Reference from the GNU-Pages. I think it helps for all implementation of Scheme, because extension of the standard are
described. Most parts are easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Common Lisp programmers should look to
[http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html].

Here you must use &rest instead of >.<
(defun + (&rest numbers) ...)

Both lisp-dialects know default, optional and rest parameters.